# Using certificate from Azure key vault in pipeline

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, certificate, azure-keyvault

I have a key vault containing a certificate. In Azure DevOps I have created a library linking to this key vault and a parameter in my release pipeline referring to the certificate. For using for example passwords and usernames in this way it's very easy to do it in code, just use `password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("password")`, but how to do this with a certificate?

My current code to set a certificate installed in my local certificate store is:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certificateCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "3333333333333", true);

var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificateCollection[0]);
```

and I want to replace this so that it insteads finds and uses the certificate in my key vault. Does anyone know how to do this? There is extremely little documentation on this that I have found and one would think that it's a very common issue.

EDIT:

Ok, I figured out that I can add the certificate to my SSL settings for the app service:

[image]

The question still stands, how do I tell my code to use this certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Googling some specific search phrases I found this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code and it seems to be working now.

I simply added WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES as a parameter in my application settings and set it to '*' to load all certificates and the certificate was then placed in a certificate store according to pricing tier:

Isolated tier - in Local Machine\My.
All other tiers - in Current User\My.

The thumbprint could then be used in the normal way.

Comment: Hi PalBo, thanks for your sharing and please [mark your reply as self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)